# iOS jquery scrollview plugin does not scroll y on an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, scrollview

I am using scrollview plugin on a jquery mobile file and works great on iOS. However when I use an iframe, scroll y is not applied and its content remains fixed. How to apply scroll y on an iframe? Thank you

```
<div data-role="page" id="init" data-theme="a">

    <div data-role="header" id="head" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-scroll="y" id="cont" data-theme="a" style="border:none;">
        <iframe data-scroll="y" src="http://www.abcd.com" style="border: 0px none;" height="100%" width="100%">
        </iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="id3">
    </div>
</div>
```

all necessary jquery mobile and scrollview plugins are attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please @Jaume try this,

```
$(function() {
   $('#cont').scrollview({
      direction:'y'
   })
})
```

Else, you need to include the `jquery.mobile.scrollview.js` file.